# Screen width with SSR?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I use NextJS and I need to get screen width on server side, because I have case when I need render one component on mobile screens and another one on desktop screens, but server renders desktop version only, because it can't check screen width, but client can do it and renders another component on small screens and I get warning that content on server side and client side did not match. How to avoid it without using device, but screen width only on server side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution is by using css to control your component, instead of JS.

As you have mentioned, your server doesn't have screen/ window object, so it won't detect any width.

if I may suggest, you better to use @media-screen, and put the class of showed/hidden component on a specific number of breakpoint. If you use css framework, u can also use their classes.

Comment: Yes, but I need change some logic behavior depending on screen width, so css media queries are not for me in this case :(

Comment: as you already know, can only detect window object in client side only means you can get screen width when your app renders in client side.